# Using Marionette.js to populate subviews in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

How do I populate table rows in a table using marionette.js in backbone.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 2 types of views (CompositeView for rendering table and tbody and ItemView for rendering table rows).

```
var TableView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    childView: TableRowView,
    childViewContainer: "tbody",
    template: _.template('<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody> <tfoot></tfoot></table>')
})

var TableRowView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    template: _template('<td><%= someProp %></td><td><%= otherProp =></td>')
})
```

for more info checkout [CompositeView docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.compositeview.html)